# WIRIS Editor save as img src instead of mathml in ckeditor

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor, mathjax, mathml

I am using Wiris editor plugin in ckeditor.

The Equations i type are saved as .png in wiris_plugin/cache_folder.

is there any way to call this images as img src tag and store it in database

Answer (score 1):

By default, our plugins work in full MathML mode (http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/full-mathml-mode) storing formulas as MathML in the database. However, if you prefer, you can store them as HTML img tags changing wiriseditorsavemode=image in your configuration.ini file as detailed in the documentation link provided earlier.

Comment: i tried this but it only stores the data of `data-mathml` attributes value in database. but when i print before send it to database. it works with image tag.

Comment: We do not fully understand your issue. Please send us an e-mail to support@wiris.com with further details and/or screenshots so we can better help you.

Comment: @WIRISmathsupportteam what did not you get...your editor is saving data as a img format we have to disable it how can i do it

Comment: You may be using an old plugin, versions older than 3.50 stored formulas as img in the database, if you rather store formulas as MathML please update to the latest plugin version